# UIWEBVIEW +contents fit in frame of webview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

I am using UIwebview in my project.Where the the cotent in the webview is been filled from html data By doing below code like this:

```
[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><font face=\"Arial\" size=\"3\"</font>%@</body></html>",[[[dict_Response objectForKey:@"objects"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"detaildescription"]] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://newsletter.nobelbiocare.com/"]];
```

Now i am setting the frame of webview:-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
 if(appDel.ori_appDel == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown || appDel.ori_appDel == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
webView.frame=CGRectMake(30,150,710,450);
}else{
webView.frame=CGRectMake(30,150,930,450);
}
return yes;
}
```

Now the thing happen is in Landscape mode the content is showing in proper way.But when i move to portrait mode it automatically shows horizontal scrolling.I dont want to scroll the webview in horizontal mode.. 
Please help me..How to solve this.

I had used sizetofit and autoresizing|autofixing.
But then also it is not solving Please help me..

Comment: Shweta you can try reloading page in `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Comment: @InderKumarRathore thanks for the quick reply.But i had tried to do that.But it is not solving the issue.

Comment: put format specifier between body tag `</font>%@</body></html>`

Comment: @InderKumarRathore edited my question please check it.Is it proper.It is not making any change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@shweta

try to update your webview  in webViewDidFinishLoad: this will help you. and try to set the size in html rather than web view frame.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webview {
    CGRect oldBounds = [[self webview] bounds];
    //in the document you can use your string ... ans set the height
    CGFloat height = [[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"] floatValue];
    [webview setBounds:CGRectMake(oldBounds.origin.x, oldBounds.origin.y, oldBounds.size.width, height)];
}
```

the main concern is the method .

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.height"]
```

by using javascript.

Comment: thanks for the reply.Can u please give my the idea of how to set the size in html rather than webview frame

Comment: @shweta i have added answer please use it ... hopw this will work for you

Comment: @Abhisek thanks the webview is stop scrolling now.But the content get cut.I had tried to set the contentsize but it is creating hte prblem when the ipad is moved from landscape to portrait i.e frame.width 930 to 710.The content size remain 930 only in portarait.And it i set manualy the contentsize of webview the content get cut. :( :( Please help me..

Comment: @shweta make a independent method in which you will set the web view frame not content size. this method will call from viewWillApear: and evrytime when your device will rotate means in landscape to portrait and portrait to Landscape . and give the hight by calculating the string height by the method               – sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:

Comment: I want webview width in landscape as 930 and portrait as 710. So it will gona work?

Comment: most probably ... :) cause write now i don't have my mac with me but it should work....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12480/discussion-between-shweta-and-abhishek)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

`sizetofit` and `autoresizing|autofixing`

Write

`webview.scalePageToFit=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.It get solve my issue.But what if i want to disable the zoom in webview

Comment: if your problem is solved then keep habit of accepting answers.

Comment: for disabling zoom try this `- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return nil;
}`

Comment: My problem is partially solved.Becoz i dont want zooming funtionality.I will surely accept the answer once i get it solved.And i had already upvoted the answer.As i really appreciate the efforts.Thank a lot

Comment: after writing this method `viewForZoomingInScrollView` are you able to disable zoom ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
  [webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><div style='font-family: arial,helvetica;font-size: 14px;'>%@</div></html>",[[[dict_Response objectForKey:@"objects"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"detaildescription"]] baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://newsletter.nobelbiocare.com/"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but it doesnot effect the contentsize of the webview which get increase when autorotating the ipad.

Answer (score 1):

Try these 
1. Put format specifier between body tag as `</font>%@</body></html>`. 
2. Try reloading web view in this

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    //Reload your web view here
}
```

Comment: kumar thanks for the reply.But it is not affecting the contentsize of webview

Comment: kumar I am updating my question.I had format the specifier and reload the webview.But there is not change in contentsize of webview